# linux rename home folders and lost configuration

Tags: linux

I've changed my Home folders name, like, "Documents" I changed to "docs", "Downloads" to "downloads" and "Pictures" to "img".. but now my Desktop is not well configured, for example, my background-image for the desktop isn't found. Where to I change/configure or redo this in the good way?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Which distro are you on?

Comment: Distro isn't as important as which Desktop Environment (sorry for being lazy earlier). If it's XDG related (most of the main ones), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the applications might keep paths to files in their config files. It might be safer to create links instead of renaming the directories

```
ln -s Documents docs
```

Otherwise, you have to find all the config files and fix them, or rerun all the applications and reconfigure them.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this will clutter the homefolder with symlinks, seemingly ruining their desired result. For example, they will now see both `docs` and `Documents`.

Answer (score 1):

On many DEs, that stuff is specified in

User Level: `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`
Global Level: `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`

Example Contents:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Share"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Once you make changes, you'll need to run `xdg-user-dirs-update`

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories)